# LINQ Joins on nullable column

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am not very good with linq, seems kind of confusing to me, but I have been making my way through it.  I have the following query that I can't seem to get to work.

I get the error:

> The value for column 'empl_cctr_id' in table 'temsempl' is dbnull.

The other join might also get the same error as well but with that related tables. Please help.

```
Dim query = (From empl In EMS_DS.TEMSEMPL
             Join cctr In EMS_DS.TEMSCCTR On empl.empl_cctr_id Equals cctr.cctr_id
             Join ppcd In EMS_DS.TEMSPPCD On empl.empl_ppcd_id Equals ppcd.ppcd_id
             Where empl.empl_userid.Equals(text.ToString.ToUpper)
             Select empl.empl_sep_dt, cctr.cctr_cd, ppcd.ppcd_desc).ToList
```

Comment: Have a look into [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696888/linq-join-tables-on-nullable-columns). It might help.

Comment: Yea, I saw and tried those suggests, but that didnt work.  My problem is in the join on i think

Comment: Yes it looks like it. The accepted answer in that link has two examples. Have you tried the second?

Answer (score 0):

`Dim query = (From empl In EMS_DS.TEMSEMPL
             Join cctr In EMS_DS.TEMSCCTR On empl.empl_cctr_id Equals cctr.cctr_id into temp
             from cctr in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
             Join ppcd In EMS_DS.TEMSPPCD On empl.empl_ppcd_id Equals ppcd.ppcd_id
             Where empl.empl_userid.Equals(text.ToString.ToUpper)
             Select empl.empl_sep_dt, cctr.cctr_cd, ppcd.ppcd_desc).ToList`

Comment: While this code fragment may answer the OP's question, the answer would be much more useful for future visitors if you explain why it should solve the problem.