# where vs join. which one is better to use

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-entities

Currently I'm running some code and got some question about this. Below are the code listings of two LINQ to Entites queries.

Code listing A:

```
IQueryable list = 
    from tableProject in db.Project 
    select new {StaffInCharge = (
        from tableStaff in db.Staff
        where tableStaff.StaffId == tableProject.StaffInChargeId 
        select tableStaff.StaffName)};
```

Code listing B:

```
IQueryable list = 
    from tableProjectin db.Project 
    join tableStaff in db.Staff
        on tableProject.StaffInChargeId
        equal tableStaff.StaffId
    select new {StaffInCharge = tableStaff.StaffName};
```

What I want to figure out is which one will be better and faster if I have to select many column from many others table.

Thanks.

Comment: Your code wouldn't compile for either of them at the moment: `select new StaffInCharge = ...` isn't valid. Please update your code appropriately (ideally keeping it in a nicely formatted layout).

Comment: See my own question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551264/why-is-linq-join-so-much-faster-than-linking-with-where

Comment: thanks Steven for doing the layout.but who can teach me how to do the format layout? thanks a lot

Comment: hi, Jon Skeet. the code i have updated

Comment: thanks Tim Schmelter, based on the article. it is mean that Join is better than where clause right? but from the article that i see it is join before the select. what if it is join or where clause in the select statement?

Comment: @OysterLee: The article(actually my SO-Question) relates to LINQ-To-DataSet what is based on LINQ-To-Objects. Linq to SQL or Linq to Entities might be optimized by the DBMS in that way that a `where` clause has the same performance as a `join`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the comment from @Tim Schmelter

*"The article(actually my SO-Question) relates to LINQ-To-DataSet what is based on LINQ-To-Objects. Linq to SQL or Linq to Entities might be optimized by the DBMS in that way that a where clause has the same performance as a join."*

and the link is 
[Why is LINQ JOIN so much faster than linking with WHERE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551264/why-is-linq-join-so-much-faster-than-linking-with-where)
i think it is very useful.