# Does place of Where clause matter  in Linq query?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I have this linq Query in a C# project

```
       var query = from p in db.Posts
                    join a in db.Author on p.Author equals a
                    join u in db.Users on p.PostedBy equals u
                    where p.IsActive.Equals(true)
                    orderby p.PostedDate descending
                    select new ViewModel
                    {
                        ...
                    };
```

If I move `where p.IsActive.Equals(true)` near `from p in db.Posts`, like

```
       var query = from p in db.Posts
                    where p.IsActive.Equals(true) //Moved
                    join a in db.Author on p.Author equals a
                    join u in db.Users on p.PostedBy equals u
                    orderby p.PostedDate descending
                    select new ViewModel
                    {
                        ...
                    };
```

will it make any difference to the performance of the query?

Comment: That would depend on the query provider.  It would definitely affect LINQ to Objects since you would be joining to possibly less items than you would if you had filtered later in the query.

Comment: @MareInfinitus I'm using sql-server 2008 Database, so its Linq-to-SQL I guess...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that it will work if you'll do it, but if you are using it against a SQL database it should not make any difference. Both queries will be translated to the SQL like this one:

```
SELECT ...
FROM Posts INNER JOIN Author ON ... INNER JOIN Users ON ...
WHERE Posts.IsActive = true
...
```

Comment: It works even when it moved... anyway thanks for the answer..:)

Answer (score 1):

Concerning performance, I would strongly suggest to put 
the joins before any where.

The reason is, that the joins already make a smaller set
(the p is selected from Posts and then only 
the matching rows from Author and Users are taken.

In opposite, if you have a where near the beginning
a caresian (big) product is calculated and then filtered.
(in your special case, only one table is affected, but
the query may be altered sometime and nobody knows then
why it is slow).

Please read this SO [Why is LINQ join so much faster than LINQ where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551264/why-is-linq-join-so-much-faster-than-linking-with-where)

And more on your special case: as this is affecting a database,
the resulting SQL statements should be the same in both queries.
Have a look at it!