# Search between Two IEnumerable - LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

Hi can you guys help me with this, I have try several things.
I need to search between two IEnumerables, here is the code.

```
IEnumerable<Project> Projects = new[] { new Project {id = "1", lan = "test1"},  new Project {id = "2", lan = "test1"}}

IEnumerable<string> lan = new [] { "test1", "test2"};
IEnumerable<string> indexFiltered = ?;
```

I need to do a linq query that return the Project.id thats have any Project.lan in lan.

Any idea?

Comment: `I have try several things` Show us what have you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another efficient approach is using [`Enumerable.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344797.aspx) since it's implemented as a hash table:

```
IEnumerable<string> indexFiltered = from p in Projects
                                    join l in lan on p.lan equals l
                                    select p.id;
```

[Why is LINQ JOIN so much faster than linking with WHERE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551264/why-is-linq-join-so-much-faster-than-linking-with-where)

The Join operator takes the rows from the first tables, then takes only the rows with a matching key from the second table, then only the rows with a matching key from the third table.

Comment: I will use the Join, is faster

Answer (score 3):

I'd use a `HashSet` rather than an array, as it allows check-if-contains as an O(1), rather than O(n), operation:

```
HashSet<string> lan = new HashSet<string> { "test1", "test2" };
IEnumerable<string> indexFiltered = projects
    .Where(p => lan.Contains(p.lan))
    .Select(p => p.id);
```

Comment: +1 Learn't something I didn't know, will have a play about with `HashSet` myself in the future.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
indexFiltered = Projects.Where(p=>lan.Any(l=>l==p.lan)).Select(p=>p.Id);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 var results = projects.Where(p => lan.Contains(p.lan));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `IEnumerable.Join()`. Internally it uses the `HashSet` to do the distinction:

```
var Projects = new[] { new {id = "1", lan = "test1"},  new {id = "2", lan = "test1"}};
var lan = new [] { "test1", "test2"};

var results = Projects.Join(lan,
                              project => project.lan,
                              lanName => lanName,
                              (project, lanName) => project.id);

foreach (var result in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ID found: ", result);
}
```