# Result of LINQ.Any to string

Tags: c#, string, linq, contains

So, I check if a string contains a certain word from an array with the following statement:

```
if(stringArray.Any(s => stringToCheck.Contains(s)))
```

Simple. Now a match is found and the statement is true. But I want to know also which item in the array matched with the string. The placeholder "s" in the LINQ statement above is not available in the following clause.

Hope somebody has an idea. I could just loop through the array, yes, but LINQ looks way nicer to me. =)

Comment: `stringArray.FirstOrDefault(s=>stringToCheck.Contains(s))`

Comment: Have a look at `FirstOrDefault`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var match = stringArray.FirstOrDefault(s => stringToCheck.Contains(s));
if(match != null) {
    // match was found
}
```

Comment: 'var vMediaLvlResult = oSDP.GetMediaLevels().FirstOrDefault(s => vRequest.URL.ToString().Contains(s));'
'if (vMediaLvlResult != null)'
'{'
'   //true'     
'}'
Worked. Thank you @Christian-Hayter, I wasn't aware of 'FirstOrDefault'.

Comment: @Tigran I just needed the string. ;)

Answer (score 3):

If you want all strings in the input list that match the condition, you need to use `Where`:

```
var matchingStrings = stringArray.Where(s => stringToCheck.Contains(s))
```

If you just want the first string, you can use  `FirstOrDefault`:

```
var firstMatchingString = stringArray
    .FirstOrDefault(s => stringToCheck.Contains(s))
```

For an overview of all available methods, check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341635.aspx

For an introduction to Linq to Objects, check out the 101 samples here: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: @Tigran it wasn't clear from the question that the indexes are needed; your answer indeed provides that information.

Answer (score 1):

Another simple solution (just **one** line of code) is just make use of `Select` overload:

With select we can access to the `value` *and* `index` contemporary:

```
//Example:
string[] arr = new[] {"a", "bb", "ccc"}; 
var result = arr.Select((v,i)=>new {value=v, index=i}).Where(x=>x.value.Contains("c"));
```

this produces result like:

```
{"ccc", 2}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another (more efficient) approach is [`Enumerable.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675.aspx):

```
IEnumerable<string> matches = from str1 in stringArray
                              join str2 in stringToCheck on str1 equals str2
                              select str1;
if(matches.Any())
{
    string allMatches = string.Join(", ", matches);
    Console.Write(allMatches);
}
```

[**Why is LINQ JOIN so much faster than linking with WHERE?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551264/why-is-linq-join-so-much-faster-than-linking-with-where)

or maybe even more efficient using [`Enumerable.Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx):

```
IEnumerable<string> matches = stringArray.Intersect(stringToCheck);
foreach(string common in matches)
{
    // ...
}
```