# Find the difference of two folders and delete files

Tags: c#, performance, file-io

I have two folders : FolderA and FolderB
I want to delete the files in FolderA which also exist in FolderB. (i.e. Common files will be deleted from folderA)

How can I do this most efficiently in C#? (That's a critical point in the project and it has to be as efficient as possible )

Thanx

Comment: Are files considered equal if they have equal file name or are the other parameters (such as size, attributes etc.) also compared?

Comment: Nothing needs to be compared, the files are equal if filenames are equal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This  is easy, readable and also efficient:

```
var common = from f1 in Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderA, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
             join f2 in Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderB, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
             on Path.GetFileName(f1) equals Path.GetFileName(f2)
             select f1;

foreach (string file in common)
{
    File.Delete(file);
}
```

Assuming that you just want to compare the file names (and extension).

Comment: I am not so familiar with that syntax but it looks very compact. How can we extend it efficiently so that to delete both of the files(both on f1 and f2)?

Comment: @EngelbertCoder: Then you need to use an anonymous type. Here's the code-difference: `select new { File1 = f1, File2 = f2 };

            foreach (var files in common)
            {
                File.Delete(files.File1);
                File.Delete(files.File2);
            }`. Btw, that's the Linq query syntax. You could also use the [method syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.join.aspx) but i  prefer queries with `Joins`.

Comment: @EngelbertCoder: [**Here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551264/why-is-linq-join-so-much-faster-than-linking-with-where) are some infos on `Join` and it's performance.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the help of LINQ. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546137.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to compare file names, here is how you can do it, I did a quick test of this code and it works:

```
        string pathA = @"C:\New FolderA";
        string pathB = @"C:\New FolderB";

        var filesA = Directory.GetFiles(pathA).Select(path => Path.GetFileName(path));
        var filesB = Directory.GetFiles(pathB).Select(path => Path.GetFileName(path));

        var toBeDeleted = filesA.Intersect(filesB);
        foreach (string filename in toBeDeleted)
            File.Delete(Path.Combine(pathA, filename));
```

Comment: This answer has three disadvantages. 1. Doesn't work if he wants to search sub-directories(`SearchOption.AllDirectories`) since you're combining with the root directory. 2. Needs to load all into memory first unlike the `EnumerateFiles` methods 3. Is less extensible if OP also wants to include the file-size or other properties.

Comment: OP said he needed to compare file names only. If he's working with .NET version lower than 4, he can't use `EnumerateFiles`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 string[] FolderAFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"Path");
            string[] FolderBFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"BPath");
            foreach (string Files in FolderAFiles)
            {
                if (FolderBFiles.Contains(Files))
                {
                    File.Delete(Files);
                }
            }
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

Here's one another solution.

```
var filesInB = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("FolderB");
Array.ForEach(System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("FolderA"), delegate(string fileName){
    if (filesInB.Contains(fileName)) System.IO.File.Delete(fileName);
});
```