# Find list of values for item using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `list` that contains `int` values, I want to use linq expression to return a result where a property equals the list items values. How can I do that?

```
list<int> x = ...

var o = anotherList.where(s => s.Id == (the list values));
```

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "where a property equals the list items values". Do you mean where the list *contains* the property value? If so, think about what that might hint at... how can you tell whether a list contains a value?

Comment: what should the result be?

Answer (score 10):

```
var o = anotherList.Where(s => list.Contains(s.ID));
```

Answer (score 1):

I translate "a property equals the list items values" with "anotherList contains this list ID":

An [efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551264/why-is-linq-join-so-much-faster-than-linking-with-where) approach is using `Join`:

```
var o = from al in anotherList
        join tlId in thelist
        on al.Id equals tlId
        select al;
```

Comment: How about if there is duplicates in `thelist`

Comment: No the `join` will match the duplicates also and return them for `al`.

Comment: @Magnus: That's exactly what i've said. Duplicates on the right side are omitted(like a `INNER JOIN` in sql).

Comment: It'll match duplicates in _any_ of the lists.

Comment: No you wont. `var anotherList = new List<int>(){1,2,3}; var thelist = new List<int>(){1,1,1}; var q = from x in anotherList
join y in thelist on x equals y
select x;` will give you three 1.

Comment: You are right, i should have tested it. However, it's not clear if that is desired here.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var o = anotherList.Where(s =>list.Any(a=> a.Id == s.Id));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use an anonymous method:

```
 var o = anotherList.Where(delegate(someItem s) { return list != null && list.Contains(s.ID); });
```