# How should I change this source into LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

```
List<Node> resultList = new List<Node>();
NodeEqualityComparer comparer = new NodeEqualityComparer();

foreach (Vector3 move in moveList)
{
    foreach (Node sight in sightList)
    {
        if (comparer.Equals((Vector3)sight.position, move))
            resultList.Add(sight);
    }
}
```

How should I change this source into linq?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var resultList = moveList.SelectMany(m => sightList.Where( s => comparer
                                       .Equals((Vector3)s.position, m)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is [more efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551264/why-is-linq-join-so-much-faster-than-linking-with-where) since you want a kind of `join`:

```
List<Node> resultList = moveList
    .Join(sightList, m => m, s => (Vector3)s.position, (m, s) => s, comparer)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you really have to change it to LINQ version ...

```
List<Node> resultList;
NodeEqualityComparer comparer = new NodeEqualityComparer();

resultList = (from m in moveList
             from s in sightList
             where comparer.Equals((Vector3)s.position, m)
             select s).ToList();
```