# Function Evaluation is timed out while using LINQ in c#

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code:

```
var deletedData
    = (from c in this.DataSet.Tables["TableName1"].AsEnumerable()
       from deletedData1 in this.DataSet.Tables["TableName2"].AsEnumerable()
       where (
           (c.Field<string>("ColumnName1")
            == deletedData1.Field<string>("ColumnName2"))
           && (c.Field<string>("ColumnName1") == someString))
       select new
           {
               T1 = c.Field<string>("ColumnName3"),
               T2 = deletedData1.Field<string>("ColumnName4"),
               T3 = c.Field<string>("ColumnName5"),
               T4 = deletedData1.Field<string>("ColumnName6")
           });
```

After executing this when I opened result of `deletedData` it's showing function evaluation timed out.
Can any one help me out to get rid of this?
`Table1` has 18000 rows and `Table2` has 400 rows. My UI is hanging when I use `deletedData1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `Where` to link tables/collections in `Linq-To-Object` but `Join`:

```
var deletedData = from c in this.DataSet.Tables["TableName1"].AsEnumerable()
                  let col1 = c.Field<string>("ColumnName1")
                  join deletedData1 in this.DataSet.Tables["TableName2"].AsEnumerable()
                  on col1 equals deletedData1.Field<string>("ColumnName2")
                  where col1 == someString
                  select new
                  {
                       T1 = c.Field<string>("ColumnName3"),
                       T2 = deletedData1.Field<string>("ColumnName4"),
                       T3 = c.Field<string>("ColumnName5"),
                       T4 = deletedData1.Field<string>("ColumnName6")
                  };
```

**[Why is LINQ JOIN so much faster than linking with WHERE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551264/why-is-linq-join-so-much-faster-than-linking-with-where)**

However, since this is just a query you should materialize it somehow. So you could consume it in a `foreach` or create a collection with `ToList`. Otherwise you are evaluating it always.

Comment: Thnq so much for the answer.why should not we use where to link tables. what does 'let' mean in the above LINQ..

Comment: @user2862430: The [`let`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976.aspx) lets you store a variable in a query, so that you can reuse it later. That increases readability and performance (in Linq-To-Objects). You could also repeat the same (as you've done with `c.Field<string>("ColumnName1")`).

Comment: ThanQ so much..its working fine.. I want you to justify for above solution.

Comment: why don't we use where to link tables in linq to object