# Linq with DataTable .ToList() very slow

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

facts.UnderlyingDataTable is a DataTable

---

```
var queryResults4 = //get all facts
    (from f in facts.UnderlyingDataTable.AsEnumerable()
        where f.RowState != DataRowState.Deleted &&
            FactIDsToSelect.Contains(f.Field<int>("FactID"))
        select f);

var queryResults5 = (from f in queryResults4.AsEnumerable()
    orderby UF.Rnd.Next()
    select f);


return queryResults5.ToList();
```

The problem is this line `queryResults5.ToList();`

It returns a list of DataRows. But is super slow to do this.

I am happy to return any object that implements `IEnumerable`. What should I do? I seems the conversion from whatever the var is to `List<DataRow>` is slow.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

First, not the `ToList` itself is slow but the query that gets executed in this method. So maybe your `DataTable` contains many rows. I assume also that `FactIDsToSelect` is large which makes the `Contains` check for every row slow .

You could use `CopyToDataTable` to create a new `DataTable` with the same schema instead of a `List` since that is more natural for an `IEnumerable<DataRow>`. However, as i have mentioned, that would not solve your performance issue.

You could optimize the query with a `Join` which is much more efficient:

```
var q =   from row in UnderlyingDataTable.AsEnumerable()
          where row.RowState != DataRowState.Deleted 
          join id in FactIDsToSelect
          on row.Field<int>("FactID") equals id
          select row;
var newTable = q.CopyToDataTable();
```

[Why is LINQ JOIN so much faster than linking with WHERE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551264/why-is-linq-join-so-much-faster-than-linking-with-where)

Comment: Great that does seem a whole lot faster! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just out of interest, how long did it take before and how long does it take now?

Comment: I didn't really time it. But I would say at least 4 time faster.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with following.

```
List<DataRow> list = new List<DataRow>(UnderlyingDataTable.Select("FactID = " + id.ToString(),DataViewRowState.Unchanged));
```

You may need to change the DataViewRowState argument in .Select method.

Comment: I joined the query with FactIDsToSelect and now it is a whole lot damn faster. Thanks for your time.