# how to write LINQ Query having multiple values from one Column?

Tags: c#, linq

I need to find data from data table with multiple values from one column only.

Below is an example:

```
 var Value = (from r in datatable.AsEnumerable()
             where r.Field<string>(ColumnName).Contains("test1,test2")
             select r ).ToList();
```

Here ColumnName is my Datatable's column name and "test1, test2" are different values ( number of values are dynamic and have "," as delimiter ).

I want to make this Linq query which returns all records from datatable which have values equal to "`test1`" and "`test2`".

Edit :
Above LINQ Query returns result like below SQL Query.
 `Select * from Table where ColumnName in ('test1','test2')`

Comment: Why use Linq here at all? Total overkill for such a simple task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Split` + `Join`:

```
IEnumerable<string> values = "test1,test2".Split(',');
var matchingRows = from row in datatable.AsEnumerable()
                   join value in values
                   on row.Field<string>(ColumnName) equals value
                   select row;
DataTable tblResult = matchingRows.CopyToDataTable(); // or ToList
```

For the sake of completeness, the [**less efficient**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551264/why-is-linq-join-so-much-faster-than-linking-with-where) but more natural approach using `Contains`:

```
var matchingRows = from row in datatable.AsEnumerable()
                   where values.Contains(row.Field<string>(ColumnName))
                   select row;
```

Answer (score 0):

Build a list :

```
var filters = new [] {"test1", "test2"};

var Value = (from r in datatable.AsEnumerable()
             where filters.Contains(r.Field<string>(ColumnName))
             select r ).ToList();
```

This will be translate to what you want

```
Select * 
from Table 
where ColumnName in ('test1','test2')
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
var searchParameters = new []{ "test1", "test2" }; // or "test1,test2".Split(",")
var Value = (from r in datatable.AsEnumerable()
         where searchParameters.All(s => r.Field<string>(ColumnName).Contains(s))
         select r).ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

The clean and easy way would be to use [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/det4aw50%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

**Example:**

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("col1", typeof(string));
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"test1"});
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"test2"});
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"test3"});
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"test4"});

// Select * from Table where ColumnName in ('test1','test2')
var rows = dt.Select("col1 in ('test1','test2')");
```

`rows` is now:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can you or statement ' || '

```
 var Value = (from r in datatable.AsEnumerable()
                             where r.Field<string>(ColumnName).Contains(value1) || r.Field<string>(ColumnNamedatatable).Contains(value2)
                             select r).ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
datatable.where(r=>{"test1","test2"}.Contains(r.ColumnName))
```

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```
var Value = (from r in datatable.AsEnumerable()
                 where r.Field<string>(ColumnName).Contains("test1").Contains("test2")
                 select r ).ToList();
```

Comment: This sounds like it would cause alot of overhead and be very slow.