# How to Compare two Generic List one contain int and another contain class object

Tags: c#, generic-list

How to compare these two Generic list and get the matching data as per ID

```
List<int> _GetRecCust;
List<Tranobject> GetTransDeta;
```

*I tried*

```
var TransactionsToProcess = GetTransDeta.Where(x => _GetRecCust.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(x.ID)));
```

but not able to get a comman `ID` data.

Both having `ID` as a field.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [most efficien](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551264/why-is-linq-join-so-much-faster-than-linking-with-where)t approach is using `Enumerable.Join`:

```
var common = from x in GetTransDeta
             join id in _GetRecCust
             on int.Parse(x.Id) equals id
             select id;
List<int> commonIDs = common.ToList();
```

By the way, why is `Tranobject.Id` a string at all?

**Edit**: Since you have commented that there are `null`s, you could use `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` first:

```
var common = from x in GetTransDeta
             where !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Id)
             join id in _GetRecCust
             on int.Parse(x.Id) equals id
             select id;
```

Comment: thanks for ur rply what i am getting `Input string was not in a correct format..`

Comment: @Rahul: Probably because an `Id` was not convertible to `int`, is that possible? Do you have empty strings, `null` or white-spaces?

Comment: yes in some cases i have null as well.how to apply condition for null check

Comment: @Rahul: What do you want to do with these nulls, just skip them or link with an `id=0`?

Comment: i don't want to use null values but can i check for null as well in the same query or assign `0` to null.

Comment: @Rahul: I have edited my answer to show how to ignore these `null`(or white-space) values. You could also modify the join: `on int.Parse(x.Id ?? "0") equals id`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
GetTransData.Where(gtd => _GetRecCust.Any(grc => grc == int.Parse(gtd.Id))).ToList();
```

Comment: thanks for ur rply what i am getting `Input string was not in a correct format...`