# "invalidcastexception specified cast is not valid linq" exeception in LINQ query

Tags: linq

```
    var Player = from PSI in regConfig.Player_SeasonalInfos
              from PPI in regConfig.Player_PermanentInfos
              where PSI.PaymentId == PlayerPayment.PaymentId
              && PPI.PlayerId == PSI.PlayerId
         select new { 
                        PlayerIds = string.Join(",", PSI.PlayerId), 
                        PlayerSeasonalId = PSI.PlayerSeasonalId,         
                        CityId = PPI.CityId 
                    };                                    

    foreach (var item in Player)
    {

     Player_SeasonalInfo PlayerSeasonalInfos = 
                              (from PSI in regConfig.Player_SeasonalInfos
                              where PSI.PlayerSeasonalId ==item.PlayerSeasonalId
                              select PSI).FirstOrDefault();
     PlayerSeasonalInfos.StatusId = item.CityId == 1 ? 1 : 2;
     regConfig.SubmitChanges();                                             
     }
```

i have write this code but i am getting excepiton"invalidcastexception specified cast is not valid linq" on line"

```
from PSI in regConfig.Player_SeasonalInfos
where PSI.PlayerSeasonalId ==item.PlayerSeasonalId
select PSI"
```

please suggest.

Comment: what about giving `var` instead of `Player_SeasonalInfo` in `from PSI in regConfig.Player_SeasonalInfos where PSI.PlayerSeasonalId == item.PlayerSeasonalId select PSI`

Comment: Side-note: don't use `Where` for linking but `Join`. All the more in `LINQ-To-Objects` ([Why is LINQ JOIN so much faster than linking with WHERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551264/why-is-linq-join-so-much-faster-than-linking-with-where)).

Comment: var is also throwing same exception