# Comparison of two large datatables is slow

Tags: c#, performance, datatable

I have two datatables A and B with approx. 50000 rows in each. I am comparing some of the columns (not complete raw) of table B to the datatable A, using two foreach  loops.
The comparision takes 2~3min to complete. Is there a way to improve performance?

```
    foreach (DataRow entry in B.Rows)
    {
        // Compare results
        foreach (DataRow dr in A.Rows)
        {
            if (entry[1].ToString().ToUpper()== dr[2].ToString().ToUpper() && entry[2].ToString().ToUpper()== dr[3].ToString().ToUpper())
            {
               // do stuff....
              entry[1]== dr[2];
              entry[2]== dr[3];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you use Linked Server? And procedure?

Comment: What kind of comparison? 2~3min is a way far away which says you're doing something wrong

Comment: Are you sre the bottleneck is actually here ?

Comment: Can you specific better what // do stuff... is?

Comment: If I were you I would do something like: create a unique hashcode for each row (using all of the contents of the row or perhaps the columns you are checking) and store it in the tables and sort the data to, then you only need to compare one column in the future, and something like a left outer join would show you the differences (the others would be the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Linq-To-DataSet`, [`Enumerable.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is much more efficient since it's using a  `Dictionary`/`Lookup` under the hood.

```
var join = from rowA in A.AsEnumerable()
           join rowB in B.AsEnumerable()
           on new { col1 = rowA.Field<string>(2), col2 = rowA.Field<string>(3) }
           equals new { col1 = rowB.Field<string>(1), col2 = rowB.Field<string>(2) }
           select new { rowA, rowB };
foreach (var bothRows in join)
{
    DataRow rowA = bothRows.rowA;
    DataRow rowB = bothRows.rowB;
    // do stuff....
}
```

[Why is LINQ JOIN so much faster than linking with WHERE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551264/why-is-linq-join-so-much-faster-than-linking-with-where)

**Update**, acc. your comment:

> I need to find and mark in the B table rows which are not in the A
>   table. So basically on your proposed solution I would like to get join
>   which will have like (entry[1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) != dr[2] || entry[2] != dr[3]))

Then you could use a combination of `Enumerable.Except` and `Join`:

```
var bKeyCols = B.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(r => new { col1 = r.Field<string>(1), col2 = r.Field<string>(2) });
var aKeyCols = A.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(r => new { col1 = r.Field<string>(2), col2 = r.Field<string>(3) });
var bNotInA = bKeyCols.Except(aKeyCols);
var bRowsNotInA = from row in B.AsEnumerable()
                  join keyCols in bNotInA
                  on new { col1 = row.Field<string>(1), col2 = row.Field<string>(2) } equals keyCols
                  select row;
```

`Enumerable.Except` also uses a set which makes it very efficient at the cost of some memory.

Comment: Actually this one working great... I have a small issue though I need to catch the case when (entry[1] != dr[2] || entry[2] != dr[3]), how would I implement this join?

Comment: @Jim: what means that you need to handle this case, do you want to exclude these rows?

Comment: I need to find and mark in the B table rows which are not in the A table. So basically on your proposed solution I would like to get join which will have like (entry[1] != dr[2] || entry[2] != dr[3]))

Comment: @Jim: try my approach above. Another way would be a "LEFT OUTER JOIN" in LINQ. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing has O(n^2) complexity, which is bad performance wise. If it is bad now, it will be even worse when you add more lines to the tables.

The algorithm would be considerably faster if you could sort both the tables before. In that case you could loop through both the tables on the same time.

Another more simple option (but not as fast) is to convert the first of the tables to a dictionary instead, to allow random access to it when looping through the second table.

### Edit

It should be possible to do this with LINQ instead, that way you won't have to do the heavy algorithm implementation yourself.

```
var matching = from br in B.Rows
join ar in A.Rows on ar[1] equals br[2]
where ar[2] == br[3]
select new { ar, br };

foreach (var match in matching)
{
  // Do stuff.
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit about loop through both the tables on the same time? any sample?

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say where is a real problem, but
you may try to use `DataTable` built-in query possibility.

Pseudocode:

```
DataView dv = new DataView(A);
foreach (DataRow entry in B.Rows)
{
   dv.RowFilter = "COLUMN_A1 = " +  entry[1] + " AND COLUMN_A2=" + entry[2];
   foreach (DataRowView drv in dv) {          
        //DO SOMETHING
   }
}
```

where `COLUMN_A1` and `COLUMN_A2` are respecive column names from `A` table

Qr simply

- first get all data you need to process in one collection
- process after that collection only once.

Consider that in this case you will have increased memory pressure.