# Filter List From List Using Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, list

I have retrieved list of my specific class with 150 records.
Now, i want only those records which have Licenseid which are in my another int List.

For example My MainList

```
List<CustomerDocument> _list = GetListByID(CustomerID);
```

In this list i have column LicenseID,CustomerID,CustomerName,Type,Age e.t.c

And SecontList

```
List<int> type = new List<int>();
```

In Int list i add LicenseID one by one dynamically.

```
Public class CustomerDocument
{
 public int LicenseID{get;set;};
 public int CustomerID{get;set;};
 public string CustomerName{get;set;};
 public int Age{get;set;};
}
```

This is my CustomerDocument class for which i am getting list.

[image: This is my debug at solution]

And now suppose, If Int list has three records , then i want those records from my Main List which have these three LicenseID in my Int List using Linq.

```
_list = ??? 



 List<CustomerDocument> list = new List<CustomerDocument>();
 List<Int> types = new List<Int>();
 MapSearchSalesEntities datacontext = new MapSearchSalesEntities();

 var collection = ddlLicenseType.CheckedItems;
 if (collection.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var item in collection)
            {
                int value = Convert.ToInt32(item.Value);
                types .Add(value);
            }
        }

var query = (from t1 in datacontext.Licenses 
              select new CustomerDocument
                   {
                       LicenseID = t1.LicenseID,
                       CustomerID = t1.CustomerID,
                       CustomerName= t1.CustomerName,
                       Age= t1.Age,
                     });
list = query.ToList(); ---gives 150 Records

  if (types != null && types.Count > 0)
  {
   list = list.Where(c => types.Contains(c.LicenseID)).ToList(); --- Gives 0 Records
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The  most efficient approach is to use `Enumerable.Join`:

```
var documents = from doc in _list 
                join licenseID in type 
                on doc.LicenseID equals licenseID 
                select doc;
```

if you want to replace the list:

```
_list = documents.ToList();
```

You could also use `Enumerable.Where` + `List.Contains` which is not as efficient but shorter:

```
_list = _list.Where(d => type.Contains(d.LicenseID)).ToList();
```

Comment: What's the reason for the inefficiency of Where+Contains? it was the first thing that sprang to my mind. Is it to do with how many times you iterate over the filter list? (join is one of those linq methods that I never quite get right in my head how it works).

Comment: @Chris:  the question is: why is `Join` faster, because it uses a set under the hood. Have a look at my own question here which i asked at the time when LINQ was still new to me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551264/why-is-linq-join-so-much-faster-than-linking-with-where Note that this applies to `Linq-to-Objects` only. So if a database comes into play it might optimize the query itself.

Comment: @Nikunj: what is not working and what means "not working" at all?

Comment: " i try both solution but this gives me list records 0 "

Comment: @Nikunj: The code Tim provided looks good. Are you sure there isn't a problem in your data?

Comment: "there is no problem in data"

Comment: @Nikunj: then provide sample data which let us reproduce the issue. I suspect that your actual model is different than what you've shown. Are these really lists or are you using a LINQ-provider that uses a database?

Comment: "I have added more specific in question"

Comment: @Nikunj: provide sample data in code not in images which aren't readable and which we cannot copy-paste. It's also not clear that there is really a document-id which has a LicenseId in the list.

Comment: @Nikunj: and you are sure that there are `CustomerDocument`s with a `LicenseId` that is either `2`, `3` or `5`?

Answer (score 1):

Using the LinQ `Where` method, this is very easy:

```
_list = _list.Where(c => type.Contains(c.LicenseID)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a linq query

```
var result =  (from cust in _list join id in type on cust.LicenseID equals id select cust).ToArray();
```