# Speeding up LINQ to SQL queries

Tags: c#, sql, linq

What are the common things that we can keep in mind while writing the LINQ to SQL query for optimizing or speeding up the  LINQ to SQL?.

For example, ordinarily, LINQ to SQL must translate LINQ queries to SQL every time a query executes; this involves recursing the expression tree that makes up the query in several stages. What we do is like precompiling the query using the `CompiledQuery` class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is one helpful thing about LINQ that every developer should know.
It is about performance of Join vs Where.

The full discussion can be seen here [why is join so much faster than where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551264/why-is-linq-join-so-much-faster-than-linking-with-where)

Answer (score 1):

usually the native LINQ2SQL compiler lets you forget about the whole optimizing queries trouble, however there are some caveats regarding mostly with compiled queries abuse.
Here are some resources you should check about it. :)

http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2010/06/24/five-tips-linq-to-sql.aspx
http://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/archive/2011/01/31/understanding-linq-to-sql-11-performance.aspx

Comment: How exactly the Linq2Sql compiler lets you forget about optimization? It's pretty basic and doesn't have any knowledge about table indexes.