# Searching different generic List<T>for common items, how can I do this better?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm

I have a class that models a person; among the properties apart from the usual is that person's mobile number

```
public class Person
{
    // Other properties elided here for brevity's sake
    public string PersonMobileNumber { get; set; }
}
```

That person is sent text messages that they may or may not respond to. I've defined a message thus:

```
public class SmsMessage
{
    public string NumberFrom { get; set;}
    public string NumberTo { get; set;}
    public string MessageContent { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTimeReceived { get; set; }
}
```

Now what I want to see is who's responded to my text messages.

In plain English you have a number of SMS messages (`List<SmsMessage>`) and some people (`List<Person>`)

In the old pre-LINQ days I'd simply have `foreached` my way through both collections, with one `foreach` inside the first but I thought that LINQ should be able to help me here. The relevant statement that I've come up with looks as follows:

```
List<Person> peopleThatResponded =
    people.Where(p => smsMessages.Exists(s => s.NumberFrom == p.MobileNumber)).ToList();
```

It just feels that this will work fine for small data sets (this is based on debugging it and watching the cycles through the code) but I'm sure that there's a more performant way to do this. FWIW I have complete control over the class definitions and can make any changes that need making.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more performat way is to join  them:

```
var peopleThatResponded = from pers in people
                          join sms in smsMessages
                          on pers.PersonMobileNumber equals sms.NumberFrom 
                          select pers;
List<Person> peopleListThatResponded = peopleThatResponded.ToList();
```

[Why is LINQ JOIN so much faster than linking with WHERE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551264/why-is-linq-join-so-much-faster-than-linking-with-where)

But that would repeat people if they have responded multiple times. Another approach is to use a `HashSet<string>` instead of the list which is much more efficient.

```
var smsNumbers = new HashSet<string>(smsMessages.Select(sms => sms.NumberFrom));
List<Person> peopleThatResponded = people
    .Where(p => smsNumbers.Contains(p.PersonMobileNumber)).ToList();
```

Comment: Is this still the case when the collection is in memory and not within a database? The example the OP gave seemed to be an in memory collection. The link you provided seems to provide reasons as to why joins are faster when querying a database using link (via ORM).

Comment: Confirming that these are two in-memory collections, if that makes a difference

Comment: @BenjaminPaul: no, the link i provided shows that  `Enumerable.Join` is much more performant with `Linq-To-Objects`(in memory). Databases often optimize `Where` to `Join`. Note that i've edited my answer to provide another approach.

Comment: @noonand: it matters, look at my last comment.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Exists` in a `where` is an O(n*m) solution, so that will get exponetially slower with more people or messages.

You can put the existing numbers in a hash set, and then match the people against that. That will be an O(n+m) solution, so it scales well:

```
HashSet<string> numbers =
  new HashSet<string>(smsMessages.Select(m => m.NumberFrom));

List<Person> peopleThatResponded =
  people.Where(p => numbers.Contains(p.MobileNumber)).ToList();
```

Comment: Guffa, I think that @Tim Schmelter has beaten you to it timewise with the edit to his original answer. I appreciate the time you took to answer the question though. Thank you!