# Get records from a collection based on a list of integer ids

Tags: linq

I have a list of integers: `ids`. There is also collection, `IdNames` which comes from an sql table.  For each integer in `ids` I want to find the matching id in, `IdNames`. Then for each record in `IdNames` that has a matching id I'd like to select the value in the `Name` and `DisplayName` columns and the `id`.

So here is the table `IdNames`

```
Id   |     Name    |  DisplayName
--------------------------------
1    |   fistName  | firstDisplayName
2    |  secondName | secondDisplayName
3    |  thirdName  | thirdDisplayName
```

If `ids` contained the integers 2 and 3, I'd want this collection to be returned

```
 Id   |     Name    |  DisplayName
--------------------------------  
 2    |  secondName | secondDisplayName
 3    |  thirdName  | thirdDisplayName
```

How would I write this as a linq query?

I stared writing it like this: `IdNames.Select(x => x.Id == ids.Any())`, but obviously it's not right.

Answer (score 1):

```
var idNames = from idName in DataContext.IdNames
              where ids.Contains(idName.Id)
              select idName;
```

Good enough?

Comment: Just make sure ids doesn't contain hundreds of records.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Join` in Linq-To-Objects(*"I have a list of integers: ids. There is also collection, IdNames"*):

```
var query = from id in ids
            join idName in IdNames
            on id equals idName.Id
            select idName;
```

[Why is LINQ JOIN so much faster than linking with WHERE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551264/why-is-linq-join-so-much-faster-than-linking-with-where)