# LINQ in C#. Check if one list contains elements from another one

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists (for example):

```
var NewIDs = new List<string>();
NewIDs.AddRange(...some values...);

var OldIDs = new List<some type>()
OldIDs.AddRange(...some values...);
```

I need to return the OldIDs list, which contains only values from the first one. I do it this way:

```
var newList = OldIDs.Where(p => p.Id.All(x => NewIDs.Contains(x.ToString()))).ToList();
```

But it returns `count=0;`

**EDIT 1:** NewIDs it's only List of strings, but OldIDs it's some structure, which have an Id propery

**EDIT 2:** It works this way:

```
var newList = new List<MyType>();
 foreach (var res in NewIDs)
   {
     newList.AddRange(OldIDs.Where(a => a.Id == res));
   }
```

I need to rewrite it without `foreach`, only using `LINQ`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`Enumerable.Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb460136%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
var newList = OldIDs.Intersect(NewIDs).ToList();
```

If `OldIDs` contains a custom object with an `Id` property:

```
var newList = OldIDs.Where(x => NewIDs.Contains(x.Id)).ToList();
```

another, possibly [more efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551264/why-is-linq-join-so-much-faster-than-linking-with-where) way using `Join`:

```
var oldInNew = from old in OldIDs
               join newID in NewIDs 
               on old.Id equals newID
               select old;
var newList = oldInNew.ToList();
```

Comment: second variant also returns count=0. NewIDs it's only List of strings, but OldIDs it's some structure, which have an Id propery

Comment: @coderman: then `OldIDs` doesn't contain objects which `Id` is contained in `NewIDs`.

Comment: Could you check **EDIT 2**, please

Comment: @coderman: the EDIT 2-code does not the same. It will add duplicate objects if the ID in `NewIDs` repeats. It's also less efficient. But apart from that both should work.  Can you show the class and some sample data which shows the issue? I have added another [more efficient](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551264/why-is-linq-join-so-much-faster-than-linking-with-where) way.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `Intersect()`, try the following:

```
var intersectedList = NewIDs.Intersect(OldIDs).ToList();
```