# how to get this data via linq

Tags: c#, linq

```
public class Employee
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class LoginAudit
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime LoginTime { get; set; }
}



static void Main(string[] args)
{

    List<Employee> AllEmployees = new List<Employee>() 
    {
        new Employee() { ID = 1, Name = "John"},
        new Employee() { ID = 2, Name = "Pete"},
        new Employee() { ID = 3, Name = "Sue"},
        new Employee() { ID = 4, Name = "Chris"},
        new Employee() { ID = 5, Name = "Kate"},
        new Employee() { ID = 6, Name = "Smith"},
        new Employee() { ID = 7, Name = "Bil"},
        new Employee() { ID = 8, Name = "Shan"},
        new Employee() { ID = 9, Name = "Joe"},
        new Employee() { ID = 10, Name = "Lure"}
    };


    List<int> SomeEmployeesIDs = new List<int>() 
    {
        1, 2, 5, 6, 10
    };

    List<LoginAudit> EmployeeLogins = new List<LoginAudit>() 
    {
        new LoginAudit() { ID = 1, LoginTime = new DateTime(2015,1,11)},
        new LoginAudit() { ID = 5, LoginTime = new DateTime(2015,2,2)}
    };

}
```

I want to select everything from employees from **AllEmployees** meeting following conditions.
1. Have ID  in **SomeEmployeesIDs** **AND**
2. Either haven't login in all ( meaning have no entry in **EmployeeLogins**) OR if their last login was over 7 days ago)

Based on this, I should be be getting Employee with IDs 1, 5, 6 and 10. Can someone help me writing Linq query to retrieve this data?

Comment: whoever voted down, can you let me know the reason. So I can lear from it

Comment: Probably because you haven't shown what attempt you've made to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: i suspect (wasnt me) because you dont show anything you tried

Comment: you have the criteria, and you know you need LINQ. So have you made any attempt to solve this? have you searched relevant topics? there are thousands of examples on filtering data using LINQ.

Comment: I am new to linq and I just don't know who how to a AND/OR with linq. I didn't find any examples but I just don't know enough about linq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this query:

```
var q = from emp in AllEmployees
        join eId in SomeEmployeesIDs on emp.ID equals eId
        where !EmployeeLogins
            .Any(el => el.ID == emp.ID && (DateTime.Now - el.LoginTime).Days <= 7)
        select emp;
```

This condition in `Any` covers both cases and the `Join` is [an efficient way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551264/why-is-linq-join-so-much-faster-than-linking-with-where) to take only  employees which ID is in the other collection.

If you don't like query syntax you could use this (if the collection is small use `Contains`):

```
var q = AllEmployees
   .Where(emp => SomeEmployeesIDs.Contains(emp.ID)
          && !EmployeeLogins
            .Any(el => el.ID == emp.ID 
                 && (DateTime.Now - el.LoginTime).Days <= 7));
```

Comment: As long as `SomeEmployeesIDs` is unique `join` is a good idea.

Comment: @pauldeter: if you insist on method syntax i avoid `Join`. Have a look.

Comment: is the one with method syntax is performance wise bad compared to one with join?

Comment: @pauldeter: no, not really. `Join` is more efficient if the collections are large, but normally it shouldn't make a difference. But as Magnus has mentioned, `Join` would "create" multiple rows if `SomeEmployeesIDs` contained duplicates. `.Where(emp => SomeEmployeesIDs.Contains(emp.ID))` doesn't have this pitfall.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need something like this:

```
var result = AllEmployees.Where( x=> SomeEmployeesIDs.Contains(x.ID) &&                     
                                ((!EmployeeLogins.Any(y=>y.ID==x.ID) ||
                                   EmployeeLogins.Any(y=> y.ID==x.ID && 
                                   (y.LoginTime-DateTime.Now).Days>7)));
```

Comment: i think this is the best way to find your data

Comment: I actually upvoted it but I am not getting desired results with it

Comment: Ineffficient if EmployeeLogins is large since you need to enumerate it twice.

Answer (score 2):

Use a query like this:

```
var employees = AllEmployees.Where(
    e => SomeEmployeesIDs.Contains(e.ID) &&
    (EmployeeLogins.All(l => l.ID != e.ID) || 
    EmployeeLogins.Where(l => l.ID == e.ID).Any(l => (DateTime.Now - l.LoginTime).Days > 7)));
```

Comment: Inefficient since you enumerate EmployeeLogins twice.