# c# Compare two lists/table

Tags: c#

I have a `DataTable` with around 30 columns it can be very large, one is called id.

In a other List I have 4 columns. I'm thinking of putting it in a `DataTable` but I'm not sure whats best.

```
name, id2, month, week
```

I want to know where `id == id2` 
and what the `month` is at that `id2`.

The both `id` and `id2` are `strings` not numbers.

Anyone have a good idea on how to do this the best/fastest way?

Comment: Join both tables on `id` column using `Linq` and get the `month`

Comment: Post here whatever you tried.

Comment: _"In a other List I have 4 columns"_ What kind of list, what kind of class, can you show it and also what you've already tried?

Comment: ""In a other List I have 4 columns" What kind of list, what kind of class, can you show it and also what you've already tried?" It comes from a text files at the moment I have put it in a DataTable. I was thinking of using a HashTable but didnt work when the id was a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could join both collections with LINQ:

```
var query = from row in dataTable.AsEnumerable()
            join obj in list
            on row.Field<string>("id") equals obj.id2
            select obj.month;
```

[`Enumerable.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675(v=vs.110).aspx) is [an efficient way to link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551264/why-is-linq-join-so-much-faster-than-linking-with-where) since it's using a set under the hood.

Now you can execute this query for example with a `foreach` loop or with `ToList/ToArray` to create a collection.

Comment: Is this possible also if I have my 2nd list in a DataTable also?

Comment: @Akjell: of course you could add all your objects in that list into a `DataTable`. Then you can also join both tables if that is what you want. But you don't need it. A `DataTable` is weakly typed whereas a `List<T>` is strongly typed which is better since you don't need to always cast everything to the correct type.

Answer (score 1):

Solution without LINQ:

Loop through the smaller list (either the list with `id` or the list with `id2`)

For each list item, search if id exists in the other list.

As you see, it is important to have a fast search (either some index or a O(log n) search algorithm)