# Filtering a linq using another list of values

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I have a list of client history data, which has phone numbers too. 
I need to filter the history data based on my list of phone numbers, here is my code

**History class**

```
 public class MessengerHistory
    {
        public Int64 ClientId;
        public string FirstName;
        public string LastName;
        public string ChartNumber;
        public string PhoneNumber;
        public string PetName;
        public string Messagetext;
    }

List<string> phonenumber = List<string>{ "12345","45678","35487"}
```

I getting list of message history from api call

```
var messageOverview = messengerAppWorkflow.GetMessageOverview();
    List<MessageHistroy> mHistory = messageOverview.messages.Select(item => item.clientPhone).ToList();
```

I want to filter the `mHistory` values to return the history values which matches my `phonenumber` list using `linq`.

Comment: i updated my question there was a mistake before

Comment: sorry updated is the right one. it was copy paste mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could join them:

```
var query = from msg in messengerAppWorkflow.GetMessageHistory()
            join phone in phonenumber
            on msg.PhoneNumber equals phone
            select msg;
List<MessageHistroy> mHistory = query.ToList();
```

another [less efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551264/why-is-linq-join-so-much-faster-than-linking-with-where) way is using `Enumerable.Where` + `Contains`:

```
List<MessengerHistory> mHistory = messengerAppWorkflow.GetMessageHistory()
    .Where(msg => phonenumber.Contains(msg.PhoneNumber))
    .ToList():
```

Comment: thanks tim its working, i have to wait for 12 min to accept. how to achieve the same using lambda?

Comment: I don't like using method syntax when it comes to joins, its making the code abstruse ;) But it's important to note that the query in the first snippet is as efficient as using a one liner.

Answer (score -1):

//This is what you already have

```
        List<MessengerHistory> reqMessengerHistoryList = new List<MessengerHistory>();

        List<string> phoneNumberList = new List<string> { "12345", "45678", "35487" };
```

//Suppose messengerHistoryList  is the list you get from api:

```
        List<MessengerHistory> messengerHistoryList = new List<MessengerHistory>();
        MessengerHistory messengerHistory1 = new MessengerHistory
        {
            ClientId = 123,
            FirstName = "Rahul",
            LastName = "Manhotra",
            ChartNumber = "abc",
            PhoneNumber = "12345",
            PetName = "pqr",
            Messagetext = "This is simple"
        };
        MessengerHistory messengerHistory2 = new MessengerHistory
        {
            ClientId = 123,
            FirstName = "Peter",
            LastName = "stuv",
            ChartNumber = "abc",
            PhoneNumber = "34534",
            PetName = "stu",
            Messagetext = "This is hard"
        };
        messengerHistoryList.Add(messengerHistory1);
        messengerHistoryList.Add(messengerHistory2);
```

//This is what you require to do:

```
        foreach (var item in messengerHistoryList)
        {
            if (phoneNumberList.Contains(item.PhoneNumber))
            {
                requiredMessengerHistoryList.Add(item);
            }
        }
       return requiredMessengerHistoryList;
```

Comment: @simran..user is expecting the LINQ version of answer