# List<T> add to T when id match

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 lists of 2 different objects:

```
public class A {
    string Id;
    string Name;
    List<B> listofB;
}

public class B {
    string Id;
    string Test;
}
```

The Id in `B` is the same as the Id in `A`

now I have 2 lists

```
var listA = new List<A>();
var listB = new List<B>();
```

How would you add every `B` object where the Id's match to the list of `A` via linq?

for now I did:

```
foreach(var a in listA){
   a.listofB = listB.FindAll(i => i.Id == a.Id);
}
```

But I would think there is a better way of doing this

*(This always returns null for now, still trying to figure out why)*

Comment: Can you add more sample code in order to test for us? Also, what is `findAll`?

Comment: findAll is a linq function

Comment: _"But I would think there is a better way of doing this"_
If that's working for you, why do you think that there's something better? It's readable and probably efficient.

Comment: He probably means [`List<T>.FindAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fh1w7y8z(v=vs.110).aspx) (which is not part of LINQ btw)

Comment: FindAll should return an empty list (if no elements found): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fh1w7y8z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx not null.
I think you should provide more code in order for us to help and I think it's more likely a lazy loading problem.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I would think there are queries for better inner linking objects, instead of a simple foreach.

Comment: @dcastro indeed that  is the one, srry I was thinking it was part of linq

Comment: @Kiwi You're not necessarily linking objects though, you're assigning a property of each item in a `List`, which requires iteration.

Comment: What you have is good enough. I would remove the items from listB after adding them to list A though. Like this: listB.RemoveAll(x => x.Id == a.Id);

Answer (score 4):

> But I would think there is a better way of doing this

If that's working for you, why do you think that there's something better? It's readable and probably efficient.

However, you could use `Enumerable.Join` + `GroupBy`:

```
var idGrps = from a in listA
             join b in listB
             on a.Id equals b.Id into bGroup
             select new { a, bGroup };
foreach (var grp in idGrps)
{
    grp.a.listofB = grp.bGroup.ToList();
}
```

But even if `Join` [is more efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551264/why-is-linq-join-so-much-faster-than-linking-with-where) if the lists are large, it's not as readable.   Maybe it's better to initialize the list from the `A`-constructor from the start instead of maintaining two lists.

Answer (score 1):

Use [GroupJoin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupjoin%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

```
void Main()
{
    var alist = new List<A>();
    var blist = new List<B>();

    result = alist.GroupJoin(
        blist,
        a=>a.Id,    //Pick group key from A
        b=>b.Id,    //Pick group key from B
        (singleA,manyB)=>
            new{TheA=singleA,AllTheBs=manyB.ToList()}); //Create a resulting object.
}
```

Comment: `Enumerable.Join` or `GroupJoin` is a strong indicator to use query syntax ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a GroupBy clause:

```
var theBsById = listB.GroupBy(b => b.Id);
```

and then:

```
foreach(IGrouping<int, B> grouping in theBsById)
{
    A theA = listA.Where(a => a.Id == grouping.Key).FirstOrDefault();
    if (theA != null)
    {
        theA.listofB = grouping.ToList();
    }
}
```

(This would only update the listofBs in the As that have Ids in listB)

or:

```
foreach(var a in listA)
{
    a.listofB = theBsById
      .Where(grouping => grouping.Key == a.Id)
      .SelectMany(grouping => grouping)
      .ToList();
}
```

(this would update the listofB for all As, which is what your code above does, too.)

Comment: If this is really more readable and more efficient than the approach the OP currently uses is another question...

Comment: You replaced a solution with 2 nested iterations with a solution that uses 2 nested iterations and a GroupBy Iteration and lost readability in the process.