# Copy to Datatable

Tags: c#, datatable

I am joining datatables to create a new datatable,

Code :

```
var row = from r0w1 in dt_vi.AsEnumerable()
              join r0w2 in dt_w.AsEnumerable()
              on r0w1.Field<int>("ID") equals r0w2.Field<int>("iD")
              join r0w3 in dt_re.AsEnumerable()
              on r0w1.Field<int?>("ID") equals r0w3.Field<int?>("id")
              join r0w4 in dt_def.AsEnumerable()
              on r0w1.Field<int?>("ID") equals r0w4.Field<int?>("id") into ps
              from r0w4 in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select r0w1.ItemArray.Concat(r0w2.ItemArray.Concat(r0w3.ItemArray.Concat(r0w4 != null ? r0w4.ItemArray : new object[] { }))).ToArray();


foreach (object[] values in row)
    dt.Rows.Add(values);
```

In the above code,

```
foreach (object[] values in row)
    dt.Rows.Add(values);
```

is slow for hundreds of thousands of rows. I want to put the data of `row` into `dt`

I want to know if there is any way exists so, that I don't have to use loop to create a new datatable ?

Comment: I think that you need the datatable.Merge method here.

Comment: What is " thousand hundreds"? Do you mean "hundred  thousand", what means _slow_? In general LINQ also uses loops and there is no other way to fill your table (even `DataTable.Merge` uses a loop).

Comment: @TimSchmelter, LINQ seems to use some better way of looping, since I always found LINQs faster than my loops.

Comment: @HarshitShrivastava: yes, a `Join` uses a set based approach   which is not exactly a loop and [is more efficient in most cases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551264/why-is-linq-join-so-much-faster-than-linking-with-where). But that's just the query. If you want to fill a fifth table with the results you need a loop.

Comment: Why not using [CopyToDataTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Data.DataTableExtensions.CopyToDataTable%60%601);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.2);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true)?

Comment: I tried `dt=row.CopyToDataTable();` but it is giving error.

Comment: You should use it on `IEnumerable<T>where T : DataRow`

Answer (score 1):

As @Thanos Markow mentioned, you need to use `dataTable.Merge(the second data table)`.

**An Important Note**: The merge operation takes into account only the original table, and the table to be merged. Child tables are not affected or included. If a table has one or more child tables, defined as part of a relationship, each child table must be merged individually.

Comment: But `Merge` also uses loops, so i doubt that this will be faster if it works at all for OP.

Comment: I want to put `row` into `dt` not `dt_vi`.

Comment: How is it usable for me ? `row` is not a datatable.

Comment: You create a new dataTable which has created from all the tables you merged.
I think it should be faster than the Join result.

Comment: How can I create datatable via joining datatables ? What is the procedure ?