# Use LINQ to get items in one List<>, that are in another List<>

Tags: c#, linq

I would assume there's a simple LINQ query to do this, I'm just not exactly sure how. Please see code snippet below, the comment explains what I'd like to do:

```
class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    List<Person> peopleList1 = new List<Person>();
    peopleList1.Add(new Person() { ID = 1 });
    peopleList1.Add(new Person() { ID = 2 });
    peopleList1.Add(new Person() { ID = 3 });
    peopleList1.Add(new Person() { ID = 4});
    peopleList1.Add(new Person() { ID = 5});

    List<Person> peopleList2 = new List<Person>();
    peopleList2.Add(new Person() { ID = 1 });
    peopleList2.Add(new Person() { ID = 4});


    //I would like to perform a LINQ query to give me only
    //those people in 'peopleList1' that are in 'peopleList2'
    //this example should give me two people (ID = 1& ID = 4)
  }
}


  class Person
  {
     public int ID { get; set; }
  }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`var result = peopleList2.Where(p => peopleList1.Any(p2 => p2.ID == p.ID));`

Answer (score 8):

You can do this using `Where`:

```
var result = peopleList1.Where(p => peopleList2.Any(p2 => p2.ID == p.ID));
```

---

You can also use `Intersect` (`var result = peopleList1.Intersect(peopleList2);`), but that would need you to implement an extra `IEqualityComparer<Person>` or override `Person`'s `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods in a way that two `Person` instances with the same `ID` are regarded equal. `Intersect` would otherwise perform reference equality.

Answer (score 5):

I would join both lists on ID:

```
var inboth = from p1 in peopleList1
             join p2 in peopleList2
             on p1.ID equals p2.ID
             select p1;
List<Person> joinedList = inboth.ToList();
```

Related: [Why is LINQ JOIN so much faster than linking with WHERE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551264/why-is-linq-join-so-much-faster-than-linking-with-where)

If you would override `Equals` + `GetHashCode` you could use `Intersect`:

```
List<Person> joinedList = peopleList1.Intersect(peopleList2).ToList();
```

or you could provide a custom `IEqualityComparer<Person>` for `Intersect`:

```
public class  PersonIdComparer: IEqualityComparer<Person>
{
    public bool Equals(Person x, Person y)
    {
        if(object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
        if (x == null || y == null) return false;

        return x.ID == y.ID;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Person obj)
    {
        return obj == null ? int.MinValue : obj.ID;
    }
}
```

Now you can use it in this way:

```
List<Person> joinedList = peopleList1
     .Intersect(peopleList2, new PersonIdComparer())
     .ToList();
```

Both, `Enumerable.Join` and `Enumerable.Intersect` are efficient since they are using a set.

Comment: This is the best answer. Sadly, looking at the votes, nobody cares about efficiency and doing the things the right way. All thet want is a shorter/simpler way. Poor software users:( +1

Answer (score 1):

```
Product[] fruits1 = { new Product { Name = "apple", Code = 9 }, 
                           new Product { Name = "orange", Code = 4 },
                            new Product { Name = "lemon", Code = 12 } };

    Product[] fruits2 = { new Product { Name = "apple", Code = 9 } };

    //Get all the elements from the first array
    //except for the elements from the second array.

    IEnumerable<Product> except =
        fruits1.Except(fruits2);

    foreach (var product in except)
        Console.WriteLine(product.Name + " " + product.Code);

    /*
      This code produces the following output:

      orange 4
      lemon 12
    */
```

Answer (score 0):

You just can use the LINQ Intersect Extension Method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136(v=VS.100).aspx

So you would do it like that:

```
class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    List<Person> peopleList1 = new List<Person>();
    peopleList1.Add(new Person() { ID = 1 });
    peopleList1.Add(new Person() { ID = 2 });
    peopleList1.Add(new Person() { ID = 3 });
    peopleList1.Add(new Person() { ID = 4});
    peopleList1.Add(new Person() { ID = 5});

    List<Person> peopleList2 = new List<Person>();
    peopleList2.Add(new Person() { ID = 1 });
    peopleList2.Add(new Person() { ID = 4});

    var result = peopleList1.Intersect(peopleList2);
  }
}
```

Just override the Equals Method in the Person-Class. I think you could compare the ids there.

Comment: @RenéVogt Thanks, didnt completly thought about this. But I added this to the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Enumerable.Intersect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
var common = peopleList1.Intersect(peopleList2);
```

Comment: Doesn't work if you don't override `Equals`+`GethashCode`, so currently not very helpful

Comment: That would only work if Person had an overriden Equals method that defines two Person instances as equal if their ID is equal.

Comment: @RenéVogt: `Intersect` first uses `GetHashCode` before `Equals` is called

Comment: Yes, that's why the link for full implementation for `Intersect` :)