# Linq to query results of list of objects based on another list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of numbers as shown below:

```
1) List<long> list1 : 101, 102, 103
```

And I have a list of Objects, in which one property is long:

```
2) List<SomeObject> list2: 
   SomeObject[0]- (long)Id : 101,
                  Name: Adam,
                  Address:xxx
   SomeObject[1]- (long)Id : 102,
                  Name: Bran,
                  Address:xxx
   SomeObject[2]- (long)Id : 109,
                  Name: Queen,
                  Address:yyy
```

I want to query the second list if it has Id's present in list1. Meaning I should get list containing :

```
SomeObject[0]  
SomeObject[1]
```

Tried the code below with no success:

```
(from t2 in list2
          where list1 .Any(t => t2.Id.Contains(t)) == true
          select t2);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Enumerable.Contains`:

```
var query = from t2 in list2
            where list1.Contains(t2.Id)
            select t2;
```

if the values in list1 are uniqe you can also use the [more efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551264/why-is-linq-join-so-much-faster-than-linking-with-where) `Join`:

```
var query = from t2 in list2
            join t1 in list1
            on t2.Id equals t1
            select t2;
```

Your approach doesn't work:

```
where list1.Any(t => t2.Id.Contains(t)) == true
```

because `t2.Id` returns a `long` which has no `Contains` method.

If you wanted to use `Any` you could use this:

```
where list1.Any(t => t2.Id == t)
```

Comment: Maybe you can also explain why the OP’s approach did not work. He did use `Contain`, after all.

Comment: @TimSchmelter `t` is also a `long` but he doesn't check `Id` for `t`. He checks `Id` for `t2` that is `SomeObject` which has `Id`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your query is that you are trying to call `Contains` on a `long`.  Instead it should have been `list1 .Any(t => t2.Id == t)`. But instead you can just do a join.

```
from t1 in list1
join t2 in list2 on t1 equals t2.Id
select t2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the below code snippet to get the desired result, where

```
var result = list2.Where(l2 => list1.Any(l1 => l1 == l2.Id));
```