# Compare Elements in two lists and return a separate list of the original list that is different

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class that has the following fields.

```
    class StandardizedModel
    {
        public string Case{ get; set; }
        public DateTime? CreatedDateLocal { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ClosedDateLocal { get; set; }
        private string _status;
    }
```

Let's say I make two lists with this custom class.

List1 ( main list)

List2

What I am trying to do is compare the elements in the two lists, if they are different I need to return the original StandardizedModel from list1.

The two lists will always be the same size and the case will always exist in both lists, the dates and status can be different though.

I've tried using a linq's zip to try and compare the elements and then add them to a list but that returns 0.

```
List<StandardizedModel> testList = new List<StandardizedModel>();

            var test = List1.Zip(List2, (a, b) =>
            {
                if (a =! b) { testList.Add(a);}
                return testList;
            });
```

Comment: ... And can you show us your code so far?

Comment: " if they are different I need to return the original StandardizedModel from list1" And what do you return if they're the same? Aren't you just *always* returning the item from list1 then?

Comment: added some example code i've been fiddling with to try and get it to work.

Comment: @itsme86, if they are the same I don't need to know so i'm just discarding it. If they are different then I need to run some more code on it.

Comment: *and the case will always exist in both lists, the dates and status can be different though.*.. so Case can *exist* but that doesn't mean that they will be the *same*. So can Case have the potential to be different as well as the dates and status?

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid gthe Case is basically an ID that I lookup in another DB to pull the second list. So the case will always be the same but the dates and status can be different.

Comment: @Tbooty: fyi, `Zip` is the wrong method if you want to link two collections by equality. Zip just uses the index of each element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Enumerable.Join` which is  [efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551264/why-is-linq-join-so-much-faster-than-linking-with-where):

```
var changes = from m1 in list1
              join m2 in list2 on m1.Case equals m2.Case
              where  m1.CreatedDateLocal != m2.CreatedDateLocal
                ||   m1.ClosedDateLocal  != m2.ClosedDateLocal
                ||   m1._status != m2._status
              select m1;
List<StandardizedModel> changeList = changes.ToList();
```

Comment: This will accomplish the task but it is not the proper way to do this, unless its a throw away that will never have to be reused anywhere else.

Comment: This _is_ the proper way. Of course you can always override `Equals` or use a custom `IEqualityComparer<T>`.  But that is not necessary for this special task. Actually it seems that `Equals` would compare the `Case` only and not the other properties. It works, is readable and efficient. Whats wrong, was it really worth a downvote?

Comment: If this is the "proper"  how would this be reusable later on in another location with out copying and pasting this code? How does this adhere to the DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) best practice?

Comment: Why do you think that this special case must be reused somewhere else? If so, move it into a method and call that. It's an "equal case but other things different in stanfardizedmodel"-usecase. Something you need everywhere.... Not really

Comment: Well, I guess its more circumstance, both are viable answers, and both are a better answer depending on what the circumstances are. I will remove my down vote because in a one off scenario its a quick concise answer. I also updated my answer to reflect circumstance specificity.

Answer (score -1):

Your best option *For code re usability* is to override the equality implementation for your objects so that you can determine if they are equal in the way you want them, if you try to get equality on an object by default it is by reference, meaning do they point to the same memory location. Which will never be the case if they are 2 separate instances. (this is why your zip does not work) Then you can use your zip to create your list.

Comment: True apart from _"this is why your zip does not work"_. `Zip` is the wrong method since it only links two sequences by the index of each element.

Comment: @TimSchmelter the definition of set operation Zip is: Applies a specified function to the corresponding elements of two sequences, producing a sequence of the results. Which makes my original statement correct.

Comment: MSDN: _"The method merges each element of the first sequence with an element that has the same index in the second sequence. If the sequences do not have the same number of elements, the method merges sequences until it reaches the end of one of them. "_ It's the same as a for-loop which accesses elements from two sequences at the same index. It has nothing to do with items being equal.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes, that is further down, ultimately it applies the function to each element, and if the sequence id is the same, it merges the 2 records so that there are no dups. In this case he is trying to "add" something to the list based on the reference equality of a and b which will never be equal. which is why I am saying even if Zip was the right way to do it, it would not work. If he had an overrided equality to use value properties in the object, his zip would work.