# IEqualityComparer on different types

Tags: c#, linq

Given two classes

```
class Contract
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    // . . . 
}

class DBContract
{
    public int FromID {get; set;}
    // . . . 
}
```

And two IEnumerables

```
IEnumerable<Contract> ValidContracts = Application.GetContracts(//. . .
IEnumerable<DBContract> ExportedContracts = DBAdapter.GetRows(// . . .
```

I need to find intersection of theese IEnumerables. But how do I implement IEqualityComparer, if it only has one type argument?

Comment: You could let them implement a common interface like `IDBContract`, then provide an `IEqualityComparer<IDBContract>`.

Comment: you don't have to implement IEqualityComparer.

Comment: @TimSchmelter `Contract` is a library class

Comment: What should be the result? `Contract`, `DBContract`, something else ?

Comment: @OfirWinegarten that question made me think my question is incorrect. Actually I seek `Contract` as result

Comment: So you can use Patrick's answer, just the other way around `ValidContracts.Where (... ExportedContracts.Any ...`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not use `Where` and `Any` instead? It is not as performant as `Intersect`, but it allows you to filter the way you want:

```
var list = ExportedContracts.Where(ec => ValidContracts.Any(vc => vc.ID == ec.FromID));
```

You can't use `IEqualityComparer` here since the object doesn't have any interface or base class (except `object`).

Comment: Before doing that, I would convert `ValidContracts` to an array or list.

Comment: Yeah, that might be a good idea. Or even a dictionary to improve performance.

Comment: @xanatos it is actually a custom class implementing `IList`, `ICollection` ans `IEnumebable`

Answer (score 7):

In order to operate on a collection of mixed types an `IEqualityComparer<T>`'s type argument `T` must accept a common ancestor of all types in the collection.

Since `Contract` and `DbContract` appear unrelated, and do not share a common interface, you need to use `object` as the universal base class.

This may be too complicated for your purposes: perhaps you could implement intersection by `ID` as follows:

```
var commonIds = new HashSet<int>(contracts.Select(c => c.Id));
commonIds.IntersectWith(dbContracts.Select(dbc => dbc.FromId));
```

Now `commonIds` has `IDs` of the objects that you need. Running simple `Where`s on both sides would produce two statically-typed parts of the intersection:

```
var commonContracts = contracts.Where(c => commonIds.Contains(c.Id));
var commonDbContracts = dbContracts.Where(dbc => commonIds.Contains(dbc.FromId));
```

Answer (score 2):

I would create a temporary container for `Contract`/`DBContract`:

```
public class ContractDbContract
{
    public Contract Contract;
    public DBContract DBContract;

    public int ID 
    {
        get
        {
            return Contract?.ID ?? DBContract.FromID;
        }

    }
}

IEnumerable<Contract> ValidContracts = Application.GetContracts(//. . .
IEnumerable<DBContracts> ExportedContracts = DBAdapter.GetRows(// . . .

var validContracts2 = ValidContracts.Select(x => new ContractDbContract { Contract = x });
var exportedContracts2 = ExportedContracts.Select(x => new ContractDbContract { DBContract = x });
```

Now you can intersect `validContracts2` and `exportedContracts2` however you want, and then it is easy to "extract" the `Contract`/`DBContract` from the `ContractDBContract`

Answer (score 1):

If they can't let them implement the same interface like `IDBContract` and provide a custom `IEqualityComparer<IDBContract>` you can't use `Intersect` but you could use `Enumerable.Join`:

```
var commonContracts = from c in ValidContracts
                      join ec in ExportedContracts on c.ID equals ec.FromID
                      select new { contract = c, exportedContract = ec };
```

`Join` also uses a set based approach so it's more efficient than `Where`:

[Why is LINQ JOIN so much faster than linking with WHERE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551264/why-is-linq-join-so-much-faster-than-linking-with-where)

Answer (score 1):

You could implement `Intersect` yourself, but without using `HashSet`, something like:

```
public static IEnumerable<TFirst> Intersect<TFirst, TSecond>(this IEnumerable<TFirst> first, IEnumerable<TSecond> second,
    Func<TFirst, TSecond, bool> comparerFunc)
{
    return first.Where(firstItem => second.Any(secondItem => comparerFunc(firstItem, secondItem)));
}
```

And use it like:

```
IEnumerable<Contract> ValidContracts = Application.GetContracts(//. . .
IEnumerable<DBContract> ExportedContracts = DBAdapter.GetRows(// . . .

var intersect = ValidContracts.Intersect(ExportedContracts, (contract, dbContract) => contract.ID == dbContract.FromID);
```