# Get values from Grouping result except values from list

Tags: c#, linq

it looks fairly simple but I can not get my mind over it.

I have a list:

```
List<IGrouping<byte, MyClass>>
```

MyClass object has a timestamp property, and I also have list of timestamp, now I want to know if there is elegant way to get all values from grouping list where Timestamp property is in my timestamp list?

I have solved the problem, but i think it can be solved in more efficient way. code would look like:

```
var loadedValues = new List<MyClass>();
foreach (IGrouping<byte, MyClass> value in Values)
{
    loadedValues.AddRange(value.Select(c => c).Where(c => Timestamps.Any(point => c.Timestamp == point)));
}
```

Comment: You want to add the whole group or only the objects with matching timestamp?

Comment: Only objects that match timestamp, so in any group there is a timestamp that exists in my timestamp list i want to to be added.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Join` which uses a set based approach, hence it's [more efficient than `Where`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551264/why-is-linq-join-so-much-faster-than-linking-with-where):

```
IEnumerable<MyClass> query = 
                from grp in Values
                from cls in grp
                join ts in Timestamps on cls.Timestamp equals ts
                select cls;

List<MyClass> loadedValues = query.ToList();
```