# Linq query geting list by comparing Id with an list of objects that have ids

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have the following code:

```
var translations = _context.Translations
       Where(t => t.LineId == lines.Id)
```

I got a variable named `lines` which is of type `List<Line>` every `Line` object has  `Line.Id`

Now I have another table named `Translations` I would like to get all Translations which have `Line.Id` that is equal to every `Line.Id` from the `lines` list.

How can I accomplish this in a single LINQ expression?

I need something like this:

```
 var translations = new List<Translation>();

 foreach (var line in lines)
 {
    var translation =
    _context.Translations.FirstOrDefault(t => t.LineId == line.Id);
    translations.Add(translation);
 }
```

Comment: What you are asking for is puzzling. "Which have `Line.Id` that is equal to every `Line.Id` from the `lines` list" implies that all the `Line.Id` values in `lines` are exactly the same. Is that the case? If so, you are looking for `IEnumerable.All<T>()`. If it's not, and you want to return translations that match any ID in `lines`, you want `IEnumerable.Any<T>()`.

Comment: @MikeHofer neither of those, I only want translations for those ids found in `lines` .

Comment: I added an example of what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Project an `IEnumerable<T>` of your `Line.Id` property, then use the result in your query with the `Contains` method:

```
var lineIDs = lines.Select(l => l.Id).ToArray();

var translations = _context.Translations
    .Where(t => lineIDs.Contains(t.LineId))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want only those translations that have IDs that exist in `lines`, this will get you what you want:

```
var translations = from translation in _context.Translations
                   join line in lines on translation.LineID equals line.LineID
                   select translation;
```

A `join` will be faster than invoking a LINQ query for each item in the `Translations` "table."

Comment: This would be evaluated client side, thus returning all `Translation` entities from the DB/data source, no?

Comment: Not entirely. Only those with matching rows in the lines table will be returned. But he's made no indication that's using stored procedures, and he's asking for a LINQ-based solution. This one implements an INNER JOIN between the two sequences, avoiding the need to iterate over one sequence, and, for each element, iterate over the second sequence.

Comment: @Moho LINQ Joins are almost always faster than a where. See this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551264/why-is-linq-join-so-much-faster-than-linking-with-where.

Comment: `lines` is not a table, it's a local `List<Line>`.  Unless something has changed in EF relatively recently, this would be evaluated client side, thus `Contains` in a `Where` predicate is the correct method to minimize data transfer and object construction in the client.  I would appreciate being pointed in the correct direction if I am incorrect.